# Como deixar código em php comentado de modo correto?

Tags: php

Como deixar um código de php bem comentado, de maneira onde seja de fácil leitura, entendimento e de fácil procura para futuras manutenções ou leitura de outros programadores?

Comment: É uma pergunta bem ampla, hein! Sua pergunta não ficaria melhor se você perguntasse "como documentar corretamente um projeto PHP" ?

Comment: entendi sua pergunta, mas pensando sobre a minha e a sua, não é a mesma coisa?

Comment: Você quer saber apenas do coding style ? Comentar de modo correto refere-se apenas ao escopo do arquivo. Uma resposta simples, seria: usando o sugerido pelo PHPDocumentor. Agora, se for o projeto, vc não resolve toda documentação em docblocs

Comment: Sim, como seria a melhor forma. Se é no inicio do arquivo... Usando @params, ou se é no meio do código.. ao lado de variaveis..

Comment: OK @DouglasBerdardino. Veja se minha resposta responde a pergunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usando  [Docblock Comment standards](http://pear.php.net/manual/pt_BR/standards.sample.php). Entretanto, eu pessoalmente não utilizo tags como `package` pois o próprio `namespace` já atende esta necessidade. Veja a [Lista de Tags do PHP DOC](http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/cookbook/index.html)

Tags:

> @api @author @category @copyright @deprecated @example @filesource
>   @global @ignore @internal @license @link @method @package @param
>   @property @property-read @property-write @return @see @since @source
>   @subpackage @throws @todo @uses @var @version

Exemplo simples, usado no SF2:

```
<?php

/*
 * This file is part of the Symfony package.
 *
 * (c) Fabien Potencier <fabien@symfony.com>
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code.
 */

namespace Acme;

/**
 * Coding standards demonstration.
 */
class FooBar
{
    const SOME_CONST = 42;

    private $fooBar;

    /**
     * @param string $dummy Some argument description
     */
    public function __construct($dummy)
    {
        $this->fooBar = $this->transformText($dummy);
    }

    /**
     * @param string $dummy Some argument description
     * @param array  $options
     *
     * @return string|null Transformed input
     *
     * @throws \RuntimeException
     */
    private function transformText($dummy, array $options = array())
    {
        $mergedOptions = array_merge(
            array(
                'some_default' => 'values',
                'another_default' => 'more values',
            ),
            $options
        );

        if (true === $dummy) {
            return;
        }

        if ('string' === $dummy) {
            if ('values' === $mergedOptions['some_default']) {
                return substr($dummy, 0, 5);
            }

            return ucwords($dummy);
        }

        throw new \RuntimeException(sprintf('Unrecognized dummy option "%s"', $dummy));
    }
}
```

Exemplo `full` usado em pacotes `pear`:

```
<?php

/* vim: set expandtab tabstop=4 shiftwidth=4 softtabstop=4: */

/**
 * Short description for file
 *
 * Long description for file (if any)...
 *
 * PHP version 5
 *
 * LICENSE: This source file is subject to version 3.01 of the PHP license
 * that is available through the world-wide-web at the following URI:
 * http://www.php.net/license/3_01.txt.  If you did not receive a copy of
 * the PHP License and are unable to obtain it through the web, please
 * send a note to license@php.net so we can mail you a copy immediately.
 *
 * @category   CategoryName
 * @package    PackageName
 * @author     Original Author <author@example.com>
 * @author     Another Author <another@example.com>
 * @copyright  1997-2005 The PHP Group
 * @license    http://www.php.net/license/3_01.txt  PHP License 3.01
 * @version    SVN: $Id$
 * @link       http://pear.php.net/package/PackageName
 * @see        NetOther, Net_Sample::Net_Sample()
 * @since      File available since Release 1.2.0
 * @deprecated File deprecated in Release 2.0.0
 */

/**
 * This is a "Docblock Comment," also known as a "docblock."  The class'
 * docblock, below, contains a complete description of how to write these.
 */
require_once 'PEAR.php';

// {{{ constants

/**
 * Methods return this if they succeed
 */
define('NET_SAMPLE_OK', 1);

// }}}
// {{{ GLOBALS

/**
 * The number of objects created
 * @global int $GLOBALS['_NET_SAMPLE_Count']
 */
$GLOBALS['_NET_SAMPLE_Count'] = 0;

// }}}
// {{{ Net_Sample

/**
 * An example of how to write code to PEAR's standards
 *
 * Docblock comments start with "/**" at the top.  Notice how the "/"
 * lines up with the normal indenting and the asterisks on subsequent rows
 * are in line with the first asterisk.  The last line of comment text
 * should be immediately followed on the next line by the closing asterisk
 * and slash and then the item you are commenting on should be on the next
 * line below that.  Don't add extra lines.  Please put a blank line
 * between paragraphs as well as between the end of the description and
 * the start of the @tags.  Wrap comments before 80 columns in order to
 * ease readability for a wide variety of users.
 *
 * Docblocks can only be used for programming constructs which allow them
 * (classes, properties, methods, defines, includes, globals).  See the
 * phpDocumentor documentation for more information.
 * http://phpdoc.org/docs/HTMLSmartyConverter/default/phpDocumentor/tutorial_phpDocumentor.howto.pkg.html
 *
 * The Javadoc Style Guide is an excellent resource for figuring out
 * how to say what needs to be said in docblock comments.  Much of what is
 * written here is a summary of what is found there, though there are some
 * cases where what's said here overrides what is said there.
 * http://java.sun.com/j2se/javadoc/writingdoccomments/index.html#styleguide
 *
 * The first line of any docblock is the summary.  Make them one short
 * sentence, without a period at the end.  Summaries for classes, properties
 * and constants should omit the subject and simply state the object,
 * because they are describing things rather than actions or behaviors.
 *
 * Below are the tags commonly used for classes. @category through @version
 * are required.  The remainder should only be used when necessary.
 * Please use them in the order they appear here.  phpDocumentor has
 * several other tags available, feel free to use them.
 *
 * @category   CategoryName
 * @package    PackageName
 * @author     Original Author <author@example.com>
 * @author     Another Author <another@example.com>
 * @copyright  1997-2005 The PHP Group
 * @license    http://www.php.net/license/3_01.txt  PHP License 3.01
 * @version    Release: @package_version@
 * @link       http://pear.php.net/package/PackageName
 * @see        NetOther, Net_Sample::Net_Sample()
 * @since      Class available since Release 1.2.0
 * @deprecated Class deprecated in Release 2.0.0
 */
class Net_Sample
{
    // {{{ properties

    /**
     * The status of foo's universe
     *
     * Potential values are 'good', 'fair', 'poor' and 'unknown'.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    var $foo = 'unknown';

    /**
     * The status of life
     *
     * Note that names of private properties or methods must be
     * preceeded by an underscore.
     *
     * @var bool
     * @access private
     */
    var $_good = true;

    // }}}
    // {{{ setFoo()

    /**
     * Registers the status of foo's universe
     *
     * Summaries for methods should use 3rd person declarative rather
     * than 2nd person imperative, beginning with a verb phrase.
     *
     * Summaries should add description beyond the method's name. The
     * best method names are "self-documenting", meaning they tell you
     * basically what the method does.  If the summary merely repeats
     * the method name in sentence form, it is not providing more
     * information.
     *
     * Summary Examples:
     *   + Sets the label              (preferred)
     *   + Set the label               (avoid)
     *   + This method sets the label  (avoid)
     *
     * Below are the tags commonly used for methods.  A @param tag is
     * required for each parameter the method has.  The @return
     * and @access tags are mandatory.  The @throws tag is required if
     * the method uses exceptions.  @static is required if the method can
     * be called statically.  The remainder should only be used when
     * necessary.  Please use them in the order they appear here.
     * phpDocumentor has several other tags available, feel free to use
     * them.
     *
     * The @param tag contains the data type, then the parameter's
     * name, followed by a description.  By convention, the first noun in
     * the description is the data type of the parameter.  Articles like
     * "a", "an", and  "the" can precede the noun.  The descriptions
     * should start with a phrase.  If further description is necessary,
     * follow with sentences.  Having two spaces between the name and the
     * description aids readability.
     *
     * When writing a phrase, do not capitalize and do not end with a
     * period:
     *   + the string to be tested
     *
     * When writing a phrase followed by a sentence, do not capitalize the
     * phrase, but end it with a period to distinguish it from the start
     * of the next sentence:
     *   + the string to be tested. Must use UTF-8 encoding.
     *
     * Return tags should contain the data type then a description of
     * the data returned.  The data type can be any of PHP's data types
     * (int, float, bool, string, array, object, resource, mixed)
     * and should contain the type primarily returned.  For example, if
     * a method returns an object when things work correctly but false
     * when an error happens, say 'object' rather than 'mixed.'  Use
     * 'void' if nothing is returned.
     *
     * Here's an example of how to format examples:
     * <code>
     * require_once 'Net/Sample.php';
     *
     * $s = new Net_Sample();
     * if (PEAR::isError($s)) {
     *     echo $s->getMessage() . "\n";
     * }
     * </code>
     *
     * Here is an example for non-php example or sample:
     * <samp>
     * pear install net_sample
     * </samp>
     *
     * @param string $arg1 the string to quote
     * @param int    $arg2 an integer of how many problems happened.
     *                     Indent to the description's starting point
     *                     for long ones.
     *
     * @return int the integer of the set mode used. FALSE if foo
     *             foo could not be set.
     * @throws exceptionclass [description]
     *
     * @access public
     * @static
     * @see Net_Sample::$foo, Net_Other::someMethod()
     * @since Method available since Release 1.2.0
     * @deprecated Method deprecated in Release 2.0.0
     */
    function setFoo($arg1, $arg2 = 0)
    {
        /*
         * This is a "Block Comment."  The format is the same as
         * Docblock Comments except there is only one asterisk at the
         * top.  phpDocumentor doesn't parse these.
         */
        if ($arg1 == 'good' || $arg1 == 'fair') {
            $this->foo = $arg1;
            return 1;
        } elseif ($arg1 == 'poor' && $arg2 > 1) {
            $this->foo = 'poor';
            return 2;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // }}}
}

// }}}

/*
 * Local variables:
 * tab-width: 4
 * c-basic-offset: 4
 * c-hanging-comment-ender-p: nil
 * End:
 */
```

Comment: eu acho que isso está seguindo um padrão muito especifico. Gostaria de um exemplo ou uma explicação de  um uso padrão generalizado. Já conversei com um amigo a muito tempo sobre o mesmo, e ele havia me explicado alguns padrões, porém isso foi muito tempo e não lembro.. Mas a ideia do que eu necessito é mais ou menos essa!

Comment: Este padrão é o utilizado nos pacotes pear. Você pode adotar apenas as tags que desejar. Também pode adotar outras tags, dependendo do projeto que está. Se você usa doctrine, novas tags serão utilizadas nas entidades, até porque, fazem parta da modelagem

Comment: Mas este padrão que você está citando. É um padrão generalizado? Onde a maioria dos programadores usam? Porque eu sei que os programadores cada um comenta do jeito que acha melhor. Mas boas práticas fazem que a maioria efetuem alguns "padrões" para dentro de seus códigos. E eu to querendo dar uma estudada nesse "padrão" para dentro de minha empresa.

Comment: O exemplo que citei é bem utilizado em pacotes pear. Em outros projetos, este padrão é reduzido, descartando algumas tags, mas sim, este é o padrão adotado pela maioria.

Comment: Eu compreendi seu exemplo e sua postagem. E até gostei! Mas ainda não é bem isso. É algo com mais estrutura e ou explicação...

Comment: o que é pacote pear? Não utilizo nada sobre...

Comment: Se você tem uma nova pergunta, por favor utilize o botão [Faça uma pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Bah! Esse exemplo simples ficou melhor, e já me lembrei de muita coisa e tive várias idéias! Obrigado pela atenção, e a resposta ta certa.

Comment: @JorgeB. Como assim cara, to fazendo uma pergunta dentro do contexto da minha pergunta. Não é de meu interesse saber o que é Pear, só fiz a pergunta pois estava em um exemplo do meu questionamento!

Comment: @DouglasBernardino então marque a pergunta como respondida, ok ?

Comment: @gpupo já está!

Comment: @DouglasBernardino só dei uma sugestão.

Comment: @JorgeB. de boa!